# Distribution Describing Probability That Sum of Multinomial R.V. > threshold?

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, multinomial-distribution

Suppose I have a Multinomial random variable $X\sim Multinomial(n, p)$ i.e. $n$ trials, each trial having $P$ possible outcomes with values $a_1, a_2, ..., a_P$. Is there a nice expression for describing the probability that the sum of the random variable is greater than a given threshold $K$?

For concreteness, suppose I roll 100 6-sided dice. What's the probability that the sum of outcomes is greater than 500?

Comment: There is not even a nice expression in the binomial case where $P=2$. There is a nice expression for the PMF in this case, though. So maybe you should be looking for the PMF?

Comment: Could you explain more? The PMF of what exactly?

Comment: The PMF of the sum.

Comment: I'm confused. If there's a nice expression for the PMF, then what I want can be computed from the corresponding CDF, no?

Comment: How nice is nice? Is a sum of a nice PMF itself nice? What about a nested sum?